# Add functionality to tree based system of qtDesigner UI

Tags: python, function, qt-designer

I have designed this UI with Qt4 Designing tool. Its a tree system.  Problem is I cant give functionality to each item individually. When I click Install it should run myfunc and when Uninstall is clicked myfuncUninstall should run.. So how can I give functionality to the items individually to tree based system.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
  _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
  _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
def myfunc():
  print "Hello Install"  
def myfuncUninstall():
  print "Hello Uninstall"    
class Ui_Form(object):
  def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(502, 409)
    self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(Form)
    self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 261, 341))
    self.treeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeWidget"))
    item_0 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
    item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
    item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 10, 113, 27))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.treeWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemActivated(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)")), myfunc)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
  def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "BBB", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
    self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Install Manager", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).child(0).setText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "1. Install", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).child(1).setText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "2. UnInstall", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  Form = QtGui.QWidget()
  ui = Ui_Form()
  ui.setupUi(Form)
  Form.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You should *not* edit the files generated by the Designer. The next time you modify the `.ui` and recompile it all your changes are lost. Those generated files are meant to be imported. I usually do something like `from mywidge_ui import Ui_MyWidget; class MyWidget(QWidget, Ui_MyWidget):` and in the `__init__` you call `self.setupUi(self)` and all the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect your `treeWidget`'s `itemActivated` SIGNAL to `myfunc`,

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.treeWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemActivated(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)")), myfunc)
```

which means, each time you **double click** on any node of the tree widget, or **press ENTER key** when any node is focused, it will print out "Hello Install" in your console.

You'd better connect the `itemClicked` with your `myfunc` method, and implement `myfunc` like this:

```
def myfunc(item, n):
  # print "Hello Install" , item, n
  t=str(item.text(n)).lower()
  if t == '2. uninstall':
    print '----------uninstalling'
  elif t == '1. install':
    print '+++++++installing'
```